# How can I activate buttons with just the keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, ui

Many user interface (UI) elements or dialog boxes have buttons. I would like to be able to activate a button with just the keyboard, without the mouse. How can I do this?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

For many dialog boxes you can select the option you want by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>firstletter</kbd>
where <kbd>firstletter</kbd> is the first letter of the option you want to select

Comment: Cooool!!! +1!  I had no idea.

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work once. What dialog boxes support this? What percentage of the time does this work for you given all the apps you use?

Comment: @mankoff Try it while carrying out what the original question asked and it works

Comment: I have "warn when changing" unselected so I never come across that dialog. In testing, CMD+K (keep) doesn't seem to work for me, only CMD+U (use). This answer, while useful when it works, seems to be only partially and occasionally valid.

Comment: This *doesn't* work more often than not in my experience.

Comment: As @fredley mentioned, this is not often the case. actually AFAICT it is rarely the case. Really really too bad.

Comment: Yup, unfortunately when I answered the question I tested it in the specific scenario the question described and it worked but it's not universal I'm afraid. Pity...

Comment: This works in Sequel Pro. I found it very non-intuitive, which is how I ended up here. Thank you!

Comment: I've found this to work in Office, but actually, you don't need to use `command` there.

Answer (score 145):

#### Enable Keyboard Control of the UI

```
System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts
```

Then select "All Controls" radio button at the bottom, rather than just "Text boxes and lists only".

[image]

#### Keyboard Shortcuts

- <kbd>⇥</kbd> (TAB) will move between buttons.
- <kbd>esc</kbd> (ESC) is **cancel**.
- <kbd>space</kbd> (SPACE) selects the **active** button (blue, outline).
- <kbd>↩</kbd> (RETURN) is **OK** or the **default** button (blue, pulsing, filled).
- For some dialog boxes, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>first_letter</kbd> will select the button with a certain first letter in the text (as pointed out by @Griffo).

Comment: Is this still applicable to Mavericks?

Comment: @JaydenLawson Yes, can confirm it's working on Mavericks. I don't know about Yosemite

Comment: It is actually under the "Shortcuts" tab. System Perfs > Keyboard > Shortcuts

Comment: As @ChrisWatts said... these instructions are a little outdated, but still work as of El Capitan. these instructions ARE the most reliable way to achieve what OP said. The accepted answer isn't reliable.

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It works perfectly on macOS High Sierra.

Comment: This works on the latest macOS Mojave. Thanks~

Comment: In macOS Catalina, the checkbox is now labeled "Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls" and was unchecked by default (which seems to be against the spirit of accessibility).

Answer (score 11):

To elaborate on the answers above, many (most?) dialogue boxes will have the default option in blue.  Hitting <kbd>⇥</kbd> will cycle between options, with a blue outline around the other button, but the default will remain blue.  Hitting <kbd>↩</kbd> will always select the default, <kbd>space</kbd> will select whichever button is highlighted.

In this example, pressing <kbd>↩</kbd> will 'Keep .txt' and pressing <kbd>space</kbd> will 'Use .bak.'

[image: Dialogue Box]

Answer (score 4):

In **macOS Big Sur** (version 11.3+), *System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts*

Select `Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls`

[image: Select Use keyboard navigation]

@Eric Leschinski's answer gives an overview of keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> also works for *Cancel*. And in some applications just pressing the initial letters works. Photoshop is one, but it's pretty common for other cross-platform applications too.

Typing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is a quick way to do something like *Close and don't save*.

Answer (score 0):

See full Keyboard Access at the bottom of the following screenshot:

[image: Keyboard Preferences]
When a prompt window like the one you included appears, the selected button will be highlighted in blue.
Screenshot:

[image: Copy dialog]

Then you press the <kbd>space</kbd> to action that button.

Comment: Thanks @Am1rr3zA for the previous edit but I discovered my answer didn't work so I amended it. ;o)

Answer (score -1):

Tab to move to the next dialog box.
Space to select

Comment: As stated by the answers above, this doesn't just work out of the box. You have to enable it in System Preferences.

Comment: @daviesgeek — And Tab does not switch dialog box ! Fortunately.