# Using a dropdown menu with arrow keys in Photoshop

Tags: macos

This may be a tad specific but it's one thing that irks me with OS X.

In Photoshop, if I want to change a layer style from 'Normal' to say 'Overlay', I need to click the dropdown list and select 'Overlay'. If I then wanted to change this again, I can't just use the keyboard buttons to scroll up or down the list - I need to go in using the mouse again and it's a bit of a pain.

Scrolling with the arrow keys works fine on other drop down lists like fonts etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hear, hear! Though this might be unanswerable and be because of how Photoshop is written. I've also noticed that navigating in the dialogs doesn't work as in other apps, even when [keyboard access: all controls](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7263/how-can-i-select-buttons-with-just-the-keyboard/7269#7269) is selected in the OSX preferences. Arrow keys might work in font, opacity etc. drop-downs because they allow keyboard input.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can do this with the arrow keys but there are shortcut keys for navigating the layers box

### Changing layer styles

> (with layer selected) hold down ⌥ + ⇧ (option & shift) and use the + or - keys to cycle through the various layer dropdown

### Navigation of layers

> UP  ⌥ + ]
>
> DOWN ⌥ + [

### Repositioning a selected layer

> (with layer selected) Move up a layer 
>   with ⌘ + ]
>
> (with layer selected) Move down a
>   layer with  ⌘ + [

these work for me with the CS5 version of photoshop