# Cycle though dropdown list using keyboard on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

In many situations I'd be nice to select the next list item using a keyboard.

Say I want to select "Ava 614" from the image below. I'd be nice to just hit the down arrow (or combo keys) then space bar, or return/enter to select. But that doesn't work. Up arrow selects the last item of the list, and down arrow selects the first item of the list.

**Is there a way to select the next item in a list using the keyboard?**

[image: mac dropdown list]

There's a [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11941/using-a-dropdown-menu-with-arrow-keys-in-photoshop), but still doesn't answer this specific question.

Side question: is there isn't a system global shortcut is there one for Adobe Premiere CC?

Comment: from my experience, [this works](http://imgur.com/Ny5rULA) without any special settings.

Comment: @Jackson1442 You're right, I tried in a browser and in an app. I guess it might be a Adobe specific thing then. Side question, what do you use for screen recorder?

Comment: just quicktime then converted to gif with a website. Open quicktime then select Screen Recording under the File menu

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me that this is an Adobe-specific problem. In standard macOS dropdown menus, you can navigate to and select the item you want using only the keyboard.

Up/Down keys move the cursor on the dropdown, while space is how you select the item you want. You can navigate to/from the menu using Tab. [Here's an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNZXg.jpg).

Bonus tip: you can also quickly navigate the selected menu by typing out what you want to select, for example in a select a state menu, you can click it, then type T-E-X to select Texas.