# Tab through buttons

Tags: macos, ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I select buttons with just the keyboard?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7263/how-can-i-select-buttons-with-just-the-keyboard)

How do I tab through buttons?

If I use the tab key it will change the selection (blue background glow) however if I press enter, it will always choose the default option.

See the screenshots for what I mean:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Enter activates default button, space activates selected button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to press the <kbd>space</kbd> bar whilst on the highlighted button (the one with the halo around it). If you press <kbd>enter</kbd>, it will always select the "default" option.