# How do I negotiate dialogue boxes using the keyboard only?

Tags: macos, keyboard

On Windows based machines, whenever a dialogue box pops up with multiple choice options (ie 'Abort', 'Continue', 'Retry'), you can use the 'Tab' key to cycle through those options without using the mouse.

On OSX, there doesn't appear to be an option to cycle through dialogue boxes using a key rather than the Trackpad.

Is there any keyboard shortcut to do this?

Comment: See: [How can I select buttons with just the keyboard?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/7263/1453)

Comment: Thanks for edits and additional helpful articles everyone

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/473143/how-to-tab-between-buttons-on-an-mac-os-x-dialog-box

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It is also the tab key. The difference to Windows is, that the "return" key always pushes the default button (which is the colored one). The currently selected button (which can be changed using the tab key) is marked through a colored border. If you'd like to push this button, you have to press the space bar.

For this to work you must have it enabled in System Preferences / Keyboard / Shortcuts

[image]

Comment: Just remember that for this to work you must have it enabled in **System Prefereces / Keyboard / Shortcuts**

Comment: downvoted the answer because it didn't work, then I upvoted the previous comment because that was the trick.

Comment: It would be helpful if this answer had the setting name and location of what needs to be enabled. On the shortcut menu, you have to set the "Full Keyboard Access"  to "All Controls" at the bottom of System Prefereces / Keyboard / Shortcuts menu

Comment: It used to be that you could hit command and the first letter of whatever button you wanted to press. Guess that is gone now?

Comment: On Big Sur this option is called "Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls". It's at the bottom of Keyboard > Shortcuts box.

Comment: I don't know how to toggle this behavior on Ventura, but it seems to be enabled on my system. Where is it, so I know...?

Answer (score 162):

macOS provides functionality to cycle through dialog boxes, but there is a system setting that must be enabled.

### Toggle Functionality with Keyboard Shortcut

Press <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>

### System Settings (macOS Ventura and later)

Starting with macOS Ventura, the setting is in **System Settings → Keyboard → Keyboard Navigation**. Click the toggle to enable the setting.

[image: System Settings Keyboard Navigation]

### System Preferences (macOS Monterey and earlier)

In macOS Monterey and earlier versions, the setting is in **System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts → Full Keyboard Access... → All Controls**

[image: System Preferences Full Keyboard Access]

---

### Keyboard Control Tips

[image: example dialog]

Now you can navigate dialogue boxes using the keyboard:

- Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move the focus the next button on the dialog.
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move back to the previous button.
- Press <kbd>Space</kbd> to trigger the currently selected button (highlighted border).

Regardless of which control is currently selected:

- Pressing <kbd>Return</kbd> will always trigger the default button (highlight-coloured button).
- Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> will always cancel the dialog.

Comment: This is the second part of the problem - I didn't have it enabled in the first place!

Comment: On my Mac, running OS X 10.11, *System Preferences* informs me that this setting can be changed with <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: Ctrl+F7 to enable

Comment: “`esc` will choose **cancel**” is not reliably true any more.

Sometimes it does. Mostly, it does not.

Comment: @DaveLand - According the Apple HIG: _Include a Cancel button that responds to the standard cancelation keyboard shortcuts. A Cancel button provides a clear, safe way out of a dialog and returns the computer to the state it was in before the dialog appeared. Make sure the keyboard shortcut Command-period and the Esc (Escape) key are mapped to the Cancel button._

Comment: @GlenYates Absolutely, that's the right thing to do. Would that more developers would _follow_ the Apple HIG. More and more, I find that escape doesn't do anything in a dialog, even when a Cancel button is present.

Comment: I wish official documentation laid out the Tab vs. Enter distinction. Sites just talk about making tab cycle the choices... but not how to select a choice. Enter is the intuitive answer to "choose the thing currently highlighted." Thanks for this answer, it was driving me crazy to think I was choosing "Don't Save" and seeing the file save anyway!

Answer (score 38):

Enable focusing with tab key at  → **System Preferences** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts** → **Full Keyboard Access...** → **All Controls**

<kbd>tab</kbd> moves between buttons

<kbd>space</kbd> presses focused button (with blue outline)

<kbd>return</kbd> presses default button (with blue background)

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>first letter on button</kbd> presses that button (**works sometimes**)

<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> cancels

<kbd>esc</kbd> cancels (**works sometimes**)

Comment: This is the best answer, as it more or less obviates the need to cycle in the first place

Answer (score 20):

**MacOS Sonoma/Ventura**

Turn on option at :

```
 → System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Navigation
```

[image]

**MacOS Monterey**/**BigSur**/**Catalina**

check the checkbox at :

```
 → System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts tab → Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls
```

[image]

If the checkbox is already checked, uncheck it and check it again.

Comment: While it was already checked for me. It only started working after I unchecked and checked it again.

Comment: This is the same in Big Sur.

Comment: Sabrina and @Neil thank you! I can't believe that's not enabled by default.

Comment: I wondered why it wasn't enabled by default but I've turned it off again now. Still multiple keyboard presses to get to the dialog save / dont save option, but it also causes lots of other annoyances like Outlook goes through a ton of toolbar options before you get from address to main window, and lots of other little situations like this. I just wanted to be able to press alt+n to say no to dialogs like in Windows, but this was only a partial solution with a lot of baggage.

Answer (score 6):

You can press Control+F7 (or fn+Control+F7 depending on your keyboard preferences regarding default function keys) to turn this option on/off on the fly.

Comment: This isn't listed in the dialog window any more but it still works.