# Keyboard shortcut to exit the print dialogue in safari

Tags: macos, keyboard, safari, high-sierra

When I press cmd-p in safari the print page shows up.

Escape doesn't work because I've remapped my escape key to <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd>

How do I exit this without using the mouse or escape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, use the <kbd>esc</kbd> key.

This will dismiss the dialog without using the mouse.

This shortcut work with *most* dialog boxes in macOS.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55292/how-do-i-negotiate-dialogue-boxes-using-the-keyboard-only?rq=1) for more details.

If one has remapped the <kbd>esc</kbd> key, using <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> should dismiss the dialog as well.  (Thanks to [Steve Chambers'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/33273/steve-chambers) comment.)

Comment: Spot on - and used so often I forget that I’ve used it...

Comment: Is there an alternative? I re-mapped ESC to ⌥ESC to prevent Safari exiting full-screen mode when I use it, and so now I can't close the dialogs using this method.

Comment: Well, then, perhaps remap another key combination to esc might work.

Comment: @bjbk just what I thought about writing until I read yours :)

Comment: Before Macs has an escape key cancelling was done with Command-Period. And I believe it still works.