# Accept login policy banner without mouse

Tags: keyboard, display, login, ui, accessibility

My computer setup currently has three monitors: the 15.4" built-in display of my MacBook pro, a 27" Apple Thunderbolt Display connected by Thunderbolt, and a [10" Mimo Magic Touch](http://www.mimomonitors.com/products/mimo-magic-touch) display connected to the Thunderbolt Display via USB.  The computer is running a version of OS X 10.10 Yosemite.

My computer also has a [user agreement policy banner](http://osxdaily.com/2012/01/18/set-user-agreement-on-login-mac-os-x/) set to appear at login due to the presence of /Library/Security/PolicyBanner.rtfd.  However, the Mimo monitor appears to be causing issues with the policy banner: namely, the banner is appearing partially off-screen, making the "Accept" button unclickable.  I'm not sure if this is due to the smaller size of the monitor, or the atypical monitor/driver.

Furthermore, the standard accessibility functionality does not appear to work with the policy banner as far as I can tell: I can't use <kbd>⇥</kbd> to tab to the "Accept" button, nor can I just hit <kbd>↩</kbd>.  I've also tried various combinations of modifier keys with these options.  <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (the first letter of the "Accept" button) also does not work.

Ultimately, my question is thus: is there a way to accept the policy without using the mouse and clicking on "Accept"?  If not, this seems like an accessibility oversight on Apple's part, as I would imagine this is also a potential problem for users with special accessibility needs.  It would also mean that you can no longer log into your mac with just a keyboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I activate buttons with just the keyboard?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7263/how-can-i-activate-buttons-with-just-the-keyboard)

Comment: As the OP already has tried accessibility options and using modifier key shortcuts, I don't think this is a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @Tetsujin: none of the solutions in the question you linked to work in this situation.  ⌘+first_letter does not work, and full keyboard access to tab over to the button doesn't work either.  Furthermore, full keyboard access appears to be a per-user setting, and this dialog appears prior to the login screen, so there's no user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed in OS X 10.11 El Capitan, as the banner can be accepted using <kbd>↩</kbd>.  Furthermore, the window appears fully on-screen in my scenario, rendering the need for a keyboard-only approach unnecessary for my use case.

So as far as I can tell, it is impossible to accept the policy banner without using the mouse in OS X 10.10 Yosemite, but they've fixed it in OS X 10.11 El Capitan.