# How can you cancel a mail send message failure when the menu is too large to fit on the screen?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, mail.app

Note: This is a problem I have never had before and I am not sure how to describe it in the title or here. Anyone may edit this to make it more clear.

---

I use Apple Mail on the latest OS X. This time, I sent a email to hundreds of people at once (these addresses are publicly known), just to have one of them fail and now I can't exit this menu, as seen here:

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

I force quit mail and opened it back up, just for it to happen again. I tried using tab to select "edit message," which would make this message disappear, but it didn't work. Do I have to factory reset Mail since I would need a ~4600p (34 megapixel) screen to select an option?][6

Comment: I kept pressing more random keys and I think ESC worked to solve this issue

Comment: Usually the "return" key, which corresponds to the blue button at the bottom of the message, would work.

Comment: The problem is that the default is "try again" so you will keep getting the error

Comment: Using "ALT" + the first letter of the other buttons will click the other buttons for you in most native apps- you can also use the setting "All controls" in Shortcuts in Keyboard in System Preferences. See: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7263/how-can-i-activate-buttons-with-just-the-keyboard